# access bacnet server in another network. server client running in different network

Tags: c#, server, client, bacnet

I have bacnet server and client running on different network like client IP 192.168.1.33 and server IP 10.10.10.45. both have same subnet mask address.

As bacnet working with UDP so client server not able to connect. and as i mention above both are on different network.

how i can connect these two in the above scenario?

Comment: Impossible for two devices to have same mac address.  The mac address contains manufacturer, model, serial number.  It would mean a manufacturer gave to items the same serial number.  First start by using cmd.exe and >Ping IP to make sure you have a route between client and server.

Comment: An IP starting with 10 means it is an internal private network.  IP starting with 192 is an IP on the Internet.  You would need some sort of bridge to connect the internal IP address to the internet.  Usually your gateway will prevent these connections unless you use some sort of port forwarding.

Comment: If the two networks are connected to each other through a device like a router, you may need to configure the router to accept the two different networks to send and receive traffic to and from each other. If there is an established connection between the two networks, you may need to configure the firewalls both at the server and at the client to accept and send traffic to and from the respective device / IP address

Comment: @jdweng it was a typo, its subnet mask.

Comment: @jdweng that’s not true 192.168.1.33 is a private class c network!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things here.

- Regarding the MAC address. Answer 1 above is alluding to the 6 byte Ethernet MAC address which contains the manufacturer's OUI allocated by the IEEE. However, BACnet (due to it's conception on other datalinks, before TCP/IP) refers to the datalink address generically as the MAC address (e.g. 1 byte for BACnet MS/TP) and for UDP it uses the 6 byte combination of IP Address and IP Port number as the address as the for the datalink.... and calls it a MAC address. Confusing. But there you have it. So, yes, ping you device (at its IP address) across the subnets to ensure that they are reachable. (By the way, it is not *impossible* for devices to have the same Ethernet MAC addresses if a manufacturer (or user) programs them that way. However, since the IP devices are known to have different IP addresses, it is impossible to have the same BACnet MAC addresses in this example. One other thing, BACnet defaults to IP Port 47808 for these addresses, perhaps the OP meant same Port numbers?
- Answer 2 above stating that an IP address starting with 192 is on the internet is wrong. e.g. 192.168.1.x is also an internal subnet.
- Now to BACnet. If you can ping the two devices, then you clearly have a correctly configured IP router between the two subnets. You are partially there. If you cannot ping them, make it so. (Some smaller devices may not be pingable, so put laptops or something on the subnets to ensure the IP networks are connected. Involve your IT department if necessary, this step has nothing to do with BACnet. Without it you are not going to connect.
- Next, BACnet uses broadcasts to 'discover' other devices and this is by far the most common approach. Broadcasts, by design, do not traverse IP routers. BACnet uses the concept of a BBMD (BACnet Broadcast Management Device) on each subnet to "tunnel" BACnet broadcasts across subnets. Install a BBMD on each subnet and configure each with the peer address and try discover. Many BACnet devices support this BBMD functionality internally and if so, this may need to be enabled, but be warned, now you have an 'virtual internal BBMD device' associated with your regular BACnet device, and this can get confusing.
- Altenatively, if your BACnet client supports 'Foreign Device Registration' and the other subnet already has a BBMD or BBMD support, then the client can register with that BBMD as a Foreign Device.
- Finally, if you can already ping the other device, and since you already know the IP address, discovery, hence broadcasts are not necessary, and if your devices support 'static addressing' simply enter the peers static IP Address:port for each device. But be warned, discovery will remain impossible, and some functions (broadcast Who-Has) will not work. This is NOT a recommended approach but gets used fairly often.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to individually bind to both IP addresses - if different NICs (Network Interface Cards) are used to communicate with the different BACnet 'server' devices, otherwise standard (/non-BACnet aware) IP routing set-up can allow you - as a BACnet 'client', to talk to the 2 servers - each upon their own/different network.

But try to honour the BACnet "internetwork" by setting & managing the BACnet 'network number' for each network (- in case the networks should ever be connected).